# Scanf_s dont save the value of the string

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

i am having a problem with my C program. 
Here is my main() code :

```
void main()
{
const float impo = 0.45;
const float reve = 0.28;
char name[30];
float pauto, pfab, pimp, prev;
printf("Enter the car name\n");
scanf_s(" %s", name);
printf("Enter the price of retail\n");
scanf_s("%f", &pfab);
pimp = pfab * impo;
prev = pfab *reve;
pauto = pfab + pimp + prev;
printf("Car name : %s\tCar final Price = %.2f\n\7",name,pauto);
system("pause");

}
```

The problem is that when i compile my code and enter the car name , it don´t appear later on the printf...
Can someone help me please?

Error Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwTiz.png

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should use `getchar()` instead of `system("pause")`, which is more portable.

Comment: Could also be compiler related.

Comment: If it is a C program, don't automatically cross-tag C++ (and vice-versa). The languages are different and distinct.

Comment: This is an exercise for college , here we are programing c language using visual studio express c++ , i can´t do nothing about it mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
scanf_s("%s", name);
```

should be:

```
scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name)); /* Assumes char name[42 or such]. */
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike **scanf** and **wscanf**, **scanf_s** and **wscanf_s** require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type **c**, **C**, **s**, **S**, or string control sets that are enclosed in **[]**. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

---

It has to be

```
int main(void)
```

btw.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
scanf_s("%s", name, _countof(name));
```

scanf_s is a secure version of scanf that requires a parameter for the buffer size to be entered.

Look here also, http://faculty.edcc.edu/paul.bladek/CS131/scanf_s.htm

Comment: Since `scanf_s` is already non-standard, this can be made less error-prone by using `_countof(name)` as shown [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

Comment: @user2802841 good point, my original answer was simply to explain that his usage of the API was incorrect and he had to add some version of a definition of the buffer size as a parameter.

Comment: Note: `scanf_s()` is in the normative section of the C spec.  `_countof()` is not there.